# ffmpeg - transpose then apply watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the -vf / -filter_complex options to chain two filters - a video rotate and then applying a watermark.

I've got an existing command for the watermark:

> -vf "movie=wm.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h-overlay_h [out]"

And I have a rotate:

> -vf "transpose=1"

How can I combine the two, doing the rotate, then applying the watermark?  I can't seem to get -filter_complex to work:

> -i wm.png -filter_complex "transpose=1,transpose=1,overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2:main_h-overlay_h"

It works but the video isn't rotated.

Comment: Full command and complete console output missing.

Answer (score 4):

I figured this one out - you need to chain the multiples together.

> -vf "movie=wm.png [wm]; [in] transpose=1 [rotate]; [rotate][wm] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h-3 [out]"

Set the watermark file name to [wm], but use a semi-colon to separate the start from the [in].  Then add another operation under [rotate], then chain it to [wm] to perform the transform.

Answer (score 3):

you can use -filter_complex options

example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.png -filter_complex "transpose=1,overlay=10:10" -y out.mp4
```